Mean-preserving transformation of density function
Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution function is $F$ and density is $f$. Assume the support of $f$ is $[0, 1]$. Is there any known class of density transformations $g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ that does not change its mean? That is, $g$ satisfies
$$
\int_{[0, 1]} g(x) f(x) \ dx = 1
$$
and
$$
\int_{[0, 1]} x f(x) \ dx = \int_{[0, 1]} x g(x) f(x) \ dx
$$
I assume $\mathbb{E}_F [X] = \int_{[0, 1]} x f(x) \ dx$ is known.
I'd like to allow different transformations of density at each point $x \in [0, 1]$, so I'd like to consider $g(x) \times f(x)$, rather than $g(f(x))$.
For example, if $F$ is uniform distribution and $g$ is
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1/4$ or $3/4 \leq x \leq 1$} \\
0 & \text{if $1/4 \leq x \leq 3/4$},
\end{cases}
$$
then $g$ is a mean-preserving transformation of $F$.

Do you want $g(X)$ to also be a continuous random variable? Your example produces a discrete random variable, , and the problem as stated is perhaps too broad to define all such functions.

It is sufficient to consider the case where $g$ generates only continuous variables. I'm not aiming to characterize all possible transformations of $g$, but rather to know some specific functions that preserve the mean.
